# How to calculate the prediction interval given the variance-covariance matrix in a multiple linear model?

Tags: statistics, regression, linear-regression

[image]

Given this matrix I'm trying to manually compute the prediction interval for when UNEM=7.5 HGRAD=17109 and INC=3350.The definition for the prediction interval I'm using is:

[image]

My question is from the data given how do I get S^2 and exactly what part of the formula is given by the variance-covariance matrix.

The other data given in the earlier part of the question is below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $S^2$ you refer to is given by
$$ S^2 = \frac{1}{n - p}  \lVert Y - X \hat{\beta} \rVert^2 $$
where $Y$ is our observed values, $X$ is the model matrix and $X\hat{\beta} = X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T \beta$ are our fitted values of $Y$. This value is useful since it is an unbiased estimate of the true variance $\sigma^2$.

As for how to calculate $S^2$, $S$ is given in the model summary as the residual standard error (in your case 670.4). You don't calculate it from the variance-covariance matrix, and it is accessed in your code as `summary(Model1)$sigma` (it's often denoted by $\tilde{\sigma}$ instead of $S$, hence the name).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Also is x0=(7.5 17109 3350)^T  and is $S^{2}(X^{T}X)^{-1}= \begin{pmatrix} 
2.08 &1.32  & -0.02 \\ 
1.32 & 8.61 & -0.00 \\ 
-2.11 & -4.57 & 0.00  
\end{pmatrix} $

Comment: Almost, you need to include an intercept term so $x_0 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 7.5 & 17109 & 3350 \end{pmatrix}^T$ and $S^2(X^TX)^{-1}$ needs to be adjusted accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
vcov(lm.object)
```

Gives you the covariance matrix of the coefficients, i.e., $s^2(X'X)^{-1}$. As for the prediction define $x_0 = (1, 7.5, 17109, 3350)^T$, and then

```
sd.pred = sqrt( lm.object$sigma ^ 2 + t( x_0 ) %*% vcov(lm.object) %*% x_0  )
```